# Need to un-flatten XML using XLST Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have a source XML file which I need to un-flatten into a more structured XML so that I can then process later on as a dataset.
I've tried numerous methods via apply-templates and for-each commands, but always seem to fall short.

I need to clarify the relationship between the elements. Starting from deepest element, the BookingDetail element, it should only be a child of the BookingHeader element if it's  element equals that of the BookingHeader  element. Then going up the chain, the BookingHeader element will only appear as a child to the ManifestBooking element if their two  equal. And finally the ManifestBooking element should only appear as a child to the Manifest element if their two  equal.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ShipmentInformation xmlns="http://www.tranxml.org/TranXML/Version4.0" Transaction="Actual">
    <GeneralShipmentInformation>
        <TransactionSetPurposeCode>00</TransactionSetPurposeCode>
        <TransportationMethodTypeCode>L</TransportationMethodTypeCode>
        <ShipmentMethodOfPayment>DE</ShipmentMethodOfPayment>
        <ShipmentIdentificationNumber>918072</ShipmentIdentificationNumber>
        <StandardCarrierAlphaCode>NUNCRR</StandardCarrierAlphaCode>
    </GeneralShipmentInformation>
    <Priority>0</Priority>
    <DateTimeReference SegmentId="StartTime">
        <Date>2010-11-05</Date>
        <Time>00:00:00</Time>
    </DateTimeReference>
    <Origin>
        <GeographicLocation>
            <LocationIdentifier>NUN</LocationIdentifier>
        </GeographicLocation>
    </Origin>
    <Destination>
        <GeographicLocation>
            <LocationIdentifier>SSS BARGAIN BUILDERS SUPP P/L</LocationIdentifier>
        </GeographicLocation>
    </Destination>
    <EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <EquipmentDetails>
            <EquipmentStructure>
                <Initial/>
                <EquipmentNumber>Z48GW</EquipmentNumber>
                <DescriptionCode>TV</DescriptionCode>
            </EquipmentStructure>
        </EquipmentDetails>
    </EquipmentDetailsLoop>
    <EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <EquipmentDetails>
            <EquipmentStructure>
                <Initial/>
                <EquipmentNumber>B50KX</EquipmentNumber>
                <DescriptionCode>TL</DescriptionCode>
            </EquipmentStructure>
        </EquipmentDetails>
    </EquipmentDetailsLoop>
    <EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <EquipmentDetails>
            <EquipmentStructure>
                <Initial/>
                <EquipmentNumber>B60KX</EquipmentNumber>
                <DescriptionCode>TL</DescriptionCode>
            </EquipmentStructure>
        </EquipmentDetails>
    </EquipmentDetailsLoop>
    <EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <EquipmentDetails>
            <EquipmentStructure>
                <Initial/>
                <EquipmentNumber>B70KX</EquipmentNumber>
                <DescriptionCode>TL</DescriptionCode>
            </EquipmentStructure>
        </EquipmentDetails>
    </EquipmentDetailsLoop>
    <EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <EquipmentDetails>
            <EquipmentStructure>
                <Initial/>
                <EquipmentNumber>B80KX</EquipmentNumber>
                <DescriptionCode>TL</DescriptionCode>
            </EquipmentStructure>
        </EquipmentDetails>
    </EquipmentDetailsLoop>
    <ManifestSourceBD xmlns:version4="http://www.tranxml.org/TranXML/Version4.0">
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/040</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020083905</SSCC>
            <Description>RIDGE CAP ROLL TOP.42 X 390MM DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>25</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>2</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/040</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020083912</SSCC>
            <Description>RIDGE CAP ROLL TOP.42 X 390MM DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>25</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>3</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/040</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020083929</SSCC>
            <Description>RIDGE CAP ROLL TOP.42 X 390MM DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>17</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>4</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/010</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020115484</SSCC>
            <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>484</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>5</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>3</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/010</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020115491</SSCC>
            <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>487</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>6</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/010</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020115507</SSCC>
            <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>274</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>7</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/010</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810380969598</SSCC>
            <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>149</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>8</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/020</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810380969604</SSCC>
            <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 SANDBANK</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>312</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>9</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/030</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810380969611</SSCC>
            <Description>VALLEY GUTTER.42 390MM DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>11</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>10</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074082/040</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810380969628</SSCC>
            <Description>RIDGE CAP ROLL TOP.42 X 390MM DEEP OCEAN</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>17</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>11</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>NUN/017553/010</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020081963</SSCC>
            <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 PAPERBARK</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>279</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>12</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>NUN/017553/020</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020081970</SSCC>
            <Description>QUAD GUTTER HI 115 PAPERBARK (PLAIN)</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>6</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>13</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>NUN/017553/070</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020082021</SSCC>
            <Description>UC UNIVERSAL CAP PAPERBARK</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>13</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>14</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074112/010</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810380973892</SSCC>
            <Description>QUAD GUTTER HI 115 CLASSIC CREAM (PLAIN)</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>6</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>15</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>3</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074112/050</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810380973939</SSCC>
            <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 WOODLAND GREY</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>149</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>16</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>CAM/074112/040</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020118645</SSCC>
            <Description>QUAD GUTTER HI 115 EXTERNAL BRACKET CLASSIC CREAM</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>1</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
        <DSBookingDetail>
            <SeqNo>17</SeqNo>
            <LineType>Product</LineType>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <OrderNo>NUN/017553/060</OrderNo>
            <SSCC>193168810020118669</SSCC>
            <Description>POP ROUND 90MM ZINCALUME NOZZLE/DROP</Description>
            <UnitCode1>KG</UnitCode1>
            <Quantity1>1</Quantity1>
        </DSBookingDetail>
    </ManifestSourceBD>
    <ManifestSourceBH xmlns:version4="http://www.tranxml.org/TranXML/Version4.0">
        <DSBookingHeader/>
        <DSBookingHeader>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <SenderName>BlueScope Lysaght</SenderName>
            <ReceiverName>REECE PTY LTD - CAMPBELLFIELD</ReceiverName>
            <ReceiverAddress1>35   STATION              AV vicroads 639 S6</ReceiverAddress1>
            <ReceiverAddress3>HEATHCOTE JUNCTION</ReceiverAddress3>
            <ReceiverPostCode>3758</ReceiverPostCode>
            <DespatchDate>2010-11-05</DespatchDate>
            <DeliveryDate>2010-11-05</DeliveryDate>
            <SenderReference>918072</SenderReference>
            <DeliveryStartTime>00:00:00</DeliveryStartTime>
        </DSBookingHeader>
        <DSBookingHeader>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <SenderName>BlueScope Lysaght</SenderName>
            <ReceiverName>SSS BARGAIN BUILDERS SUPP P/L</ReceiverName>
            <ReceiverAddress1>83   HIGH                 ST TO 85</ReceiverAddress1>
            <ReceiverAddress3>BROADFORD</ReceiverAddress3>
            <ReceiverPostCode>3658</ReceiverPostCode>
            <DespatchDate>2010-11-05</DespatchDate>
            <DeliveryDate>2010-11-05</DeliveryDate>
            <SenderReference>918072</SenderReference>
            <DeliveryStartTime>00:00:00</DeliveryStartTime>
        </DSBookingHeader>
        <DSBookingHeader>
            <BookingNo>3</BookingNo>
            <SenderName>BlueScope Lysaght</SenderName>
            <ReceiverName>SSS BARGAIN BUILDERS SUPP P/L</ReceiverName>
            <ReceiverAddress1>83   HIGH                 ST TO 85</ReceiverAddress1>
            <ReceiverAddress3>BROADFORD</ReceiverAddress3>
            <ReceiverPostCode>3658</ReceiverPostCode>
            <DespatchDate>2010-11-05</DespatchDate>
            <DeliveryDate>2010-11-05</DeliveryDate>
            <SenderReference>918072</SenderReference>
            <DeliveryStartTime>00:00:00</DeliveryStartTime>
        </DSBookingHeader>
    </ManifestSourceBH>
    <ManifestSourceM xmlns:version4="http://www.tranxml.org/TranXML/Version4.0">
        <DSManifest>
            <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
            <ManifestDate>2010-11-05</ManifestDate>
            <PrimeMover>Z48GW</PrimeMover>
            <Fleet1>B50KX</Fleet1>
            <Fleet2>B60KX</Fleet2>
            <Fleet3>B70KX</Fleet3>
            <Fleet4>B80KX</Fleet4>
            <Fleet5>B90KX</Fleet5>
            <Description>""</Description>
            <Description2>""</Description2>
        </DSManifest>
    </ManifestSourceM>
    <ManifestSourceMB xmlns:version4="http://www.tranxml.org/TranXML/Version4.0">
        <DSManifestBooking/>
        <DSManifestBooking>
            <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
            <BookingNo>3</BookingNo>
            <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
            <SubBookingNo>1</SubBookingNo>
            <Confirmed>"No"</Confirmed>
            <Charge>"No"</Charge>
            <SentToEDI>"No"</SentToEDI>
        </DSManifestBooking>
        <DSManifestBooking>
            <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <SeqNo>2</SeqNo>
            <SubBookingNo>1</SubBookingNo>
            <Confirmed>"No"</Confirmed>
            <Charge>"No"</Charge>
            <SentToEDI>"No"</SentToEDI>
        </DSManifestBooking>
        <DSManifestBooking>
            <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
            <SubBookingNo>1</SubBookingNo>
            <Confirmed>"No"</Confirmed>
            <Charge>"No"</Charge>
            <SentToEDI>"No"</SentToEDI>
        </DSManifestBooking>
    </ManifestSourceMB>
</ShipmentInformation>
```

Into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ManifestSource xmlns:version4="http://www.tranxml.org/TranXML/Version4.0">
    <DSManifest>
        <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
        <ManifestDate>2010-11-05</ManifestDate>
        <PrimeMover>Z48GW</PrimeMover>
        <Description>""</Description>
        <Description2>""</Description2>
        <Fleet1>B50KX</Fleet1>
        <Fleet2>B60KX</Fleet2>
        <Fleet3>B70KX</Fleet3>
        <Fleet4>B80KX</Fleet4>
        <Fleet5>B90KX</Fleet5>
        <DSManifestBooking>
           <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
           <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
           <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
           <Confirmed>"No"</Confirmed>
           <Charge>"No"</Charge>
           <SentToEDI>"No"</SentToEDI>
              <DSBookingHeader>
                 <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
                 <SenderName>BlueScope Lysaght</SenderName>
                 <ReceiverName>REECE PTY LTD - CAMPBELLFIELD</ReceiverName>
                 <ReceiverAddress1>35 STATION AV vicroads 639 S6</ReceiverAddress1>
                 <ReceiverAddress3>HEATHCOTE JUNCTION</ReceiverAddress3>
                 <ReceiverPostCode>3758</ReceiverPostCode>
                 <DespatchDate>2010-11-05</DespatchDate>
                 <DeliveryDate>2010-11-05</DeliveryDate>
                 <SenderReference>918072</SenderReference>
                 <DeliveryStartTime>00:00:00</DeliveryStartTime>
                 <DSBookingDetail>
                    <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
                    <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
                    <Description>RIDGE CAP ROLL TOP.42 X 390MM DEEP OCEAN</Description>
                    <Quantity1>25</Quantity1>
                    </DSBookingDetail>
             </DSBookingHeader>
          </DSManifestBooking>
          <DSManifestBooking>
             <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
             <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
             <SeqNo>2</SeqNo>
             <Confirmed>"No"</Confirmed>
             <Charge>"No"</Charge>
             <SentToEDI>"No"</SentToEDI>
             <DSBookingHeader>
                <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
                <SenderName>BlueScope Lysaght</SenderName>
                <ReceiverName>SSS BARGAIN BUILDERS SUPP P/L</ReceiverName>
                <ReceiverAddress1>83 HIGH ST TO 85</ReceiverAddress1>
                <ReceiverAddress3>BROADFORD</ReceiverAddress3>
                <ReceiverPostCode>3658</ReceiverPostCode>
                <DespatchDate>2010-11-05</DespatchDate>
                <DeliveryDate>2010-11-05</DeliveryDate>
                <SenderReference>918072</SenderReference>
                <DeliveryStartTime>00:00:00</DeliveryStartTime>
                <DSBookingDetail>
                   <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
                   <SeqNo>11</SeqNo>
                   <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 PAPERBARK</Description>
                   <Quantity1>279</Quantity1>
                </DSBookingDetail>
             </DSBookingHeader>
        </DSManifestBooking>
    </DSManifest>
</ManifestSource>
```

Comment: Biggest question: are you restricted to XSLT 1.0? That will make a big difference in what technique to recommend.

Comment: Before we go cross-eyed trying to infer the correspondence between your source and your desired output, can you describe in a little prose what the desired transformation is? Also, would be helpful to post what XSLT you've tried, and what the result was. I suspect the answer is going to be grouping...

Comment: The source file will contain 4 types of elements; ManifestSourceM, ManifestSourceMB, ManifestSourceBH and ManifestSourceBD. Within each element there will be one or many child elements of that type.

Comment: The transformation should create a hierarchy tree starting with DSManifest element, then one or more decendant DSManifestBooking elements, each of which will have one decendant DSBookingHeader element, which themselves will have one or more decendant DSBookingDetail elements.

Comment: The link starting from the top will be manifest# from DSManifest to DSManifestBooking. Booking# from DSManifestBooking to DSBookingHeader. Booking# from DSBookingHeader to DSBookingDetail.

Comment: OK, that helps... can you post your closest XSLT attempt, and show a sample of its output, and say how it differs from your desired output? I'm still not quite grokking the mapping from input to desired output... I don't understand what is meant by "link" and "manifest#", among others. But maybe someone else will understand, and posting your XSLT attempt will help.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:version4="http://www.tranxml.org/TranXML/Version4.0">
    <xsl:template match="*" name="copy">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="version4:ShipmentInformation/*
                            [not(self::version4:ManifestSourceM)]"/>
    <xsl:template match="version4:DSManifest/*[last()]">
        <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/version4:ManifestSourceMB/*
                                        [version4:ManifestNo =
                                         current()/../version4:ManifestNo]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="version4:DSManifestBooking/*[last()]">
        <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/version4:ManifestSourceBH/*
                                        [version4:BookingNo =
                                         current()/../version4:BookingNo]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="version4:DSBookingHeader/*[last()]">
        <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/version4:ManifestSourceBD/*
                                        [version4:BookingNo =
                                         current()/../version4:BookingNo]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="version4:ShipmentInformation">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ManifestSourceM>
    <DSManifest>
        <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
        <ManifestDate>2010-11-05</ManifestDate>
        <PrimeMover>Z48GW</PrimeMover>
        <Fleet1>B50KX</Fleet1>
        <Fleet2>B60KX</Fleet2>
        <Fleet3>B70KX</Fleet3>
        <Fleet4>B80KX</Fleet4>
        <Description>""</Description>
        <Description2>""</Description2>
        <DSManifestBooking>
            <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
            <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
            <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
            <Confirmed>"No"</Confirmed>
            <Charge>"No"</Charge>
            <SentToEDI>"No"</SentToEDI>
            <DSBookingHeader>
                <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
                <SenderName>BlueScope Lysaght</SenderName>
                <ReceiverName>REECE PTY LTD - CAMPBELLFIELD</ReceiverName>
                <ReceiverAddress1>35 STATION AV vicroads 639 S6</ReceiverAddress1>
                <ReceiverAddress3>HEATHCOTE JUNCTION</ReceiverAddress3>
                <ReceiverPostCode>3758</ReceiverPostCode>
                <DespatchDate>2010-11-05</DespatchDate>
                <DeliveryDate>2010-11-05</DeliveryDate>
                <SenderReference>918072</SenderReference>
                <DeliveryStartTime>00:00:00</DeliveryStartTime>
                <DSBookingDetail>
                    <BookingNo>1</BookingNo>
                    <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
                    <Description>RIDGE CAP ROLL TOP.42 X 390MM DEEP OCEAN</Description>
                    <Quantity1>25</Quantity1>
                </DSBookingDetail>
            </DSBookingHeader>
        </DSManifestBooking>
        <DSManifestBooking>
            <ManifestNo>918072</ManifestNo>
            <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
            <SeqNo>2</SeqNo>
            <Confirmed>"No"</Confirmed>
            <Charge>"No"</Charge>
            <SentToEDI>"No"</SentToEDI>
            <DSBookingHeader>
                <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
                <SenderName>BlueScope Lysaght</SenderName>
                <ReceiverName>SSS BARGAIN BUILDERS SUPP P/L</ReceiverName>
                <ReceiverAddress1>83 HIGH ST TO 85</ReceiverAddress1>
                <ReceiverAddress3>BROADFORD</ReceiverAddress3>
                <ReceiverPostCode>3658</ReceiverPostCode>
                <DespatchDate>2010-11-05</DespatchDate>
                <DeliveryDate>2010-11-05</DeliveryDate>
                <SenderReference>918072</SenderReference>
                <DeliveryStartTime>00:00:00</DeliveryStartTime>
                <DSBookingDetail>
                    <BookingNo>2</BookingNo>
                    <SeqNo>11</SeqNo>
                    <Description>CUSTOM ORB.42 PAPERBARK</Description>
                    <Quantity1>279</Quantity1>
                </DSBookingDetail>
            </DSBookingHeader>
        </DSManifestBooking>
    </DSManifest>
</ManifestSourceM>
```

**Note**: Your desired output has a namespace declaration but elements are under null namespace URI (If you want this, please clarify). The look up can be done more efficiently with keys for large documents. It could also be done for manifest (not just for books) in case there will be more than one.

**Edit**: Strip namespace declarations.

**Edit 2**: Added manifest binding.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly the structure I need. Namespace declaration on the output is not required.

Comment: I tested you wonderful code against my full source and it worked perfectly. It grouped the elements correctly, I even shuffled the elements around in the source and it still grouped them correctly.

Comment: I'm told that there will only ever be one DSManifestM per source file, but I would rather cater for there being more than one. I'll post a complete source file.

Comment: @Tony J: Check my last edit matching your requeriments (strip namespace, manifest binding). Please, if you are going to edit your question, also add these last comments.

Comment: Thank you LarsH for the template and thank you Alejandro, your mod's worked great. I should have asked the question days ago, but I like to try and solve problems myself. Now if you could recommend a good reference book that would be great.

Comment: @Tony J: You are wellcome, ask any time. If you talk about books and XSLT, everybody will say Dr. M. Kay's books. But I think there is some question here in SO, also. You should search that.